# Generate list of subplots in same order as they will be plotted.

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to generate three plots in one figure, each of which is a three-dimensional surface plot.  And I'm trying to generate a list which will hold them in an index position that corresponds to their position on the figure (as would be intuitive).

However, when I create an array of subplots and refer to each individually, the plots are not ordered in the way that I would expect.  An example is below - I would assume that the plots should be labelled 0, 1, 2 (but they're labelled 1, 2, 0 instead).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Modified from the `Axes3D.plot_surface` help ([here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html)):

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = plt.figaspect(0.333))
ax = [fig.add_subplot(1, 3, x, projection = '3d') for x in range(3)]

X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)

for i in range(3):
    ax[i].plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
    ax[i].set_zlim(-1.01, 1.01)
    ax[i].set_title("Plot " +str(i))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_subplot` takes the arguments `nrows`, `ncols`, and plot_number, where plot_number should start at 1, not zero. See the [docs here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot) for more.

So, change you line to:

```
ax = [fig.add_subplot(1, 3, x+1, projection = '3d') for x in range(3)]
```

(note the `x+1` in place of `x`), and all should work out ok